# Cisco IOS nat inside not working working after reboot

Tags: cisco-ios

I have a strange problem - after rebooting my Cisco 867 router running IOS 15.5 all inside NAT translations do not work until I remove and re-establish the access group on the outside interface. I'm sure there is an ordering problem on reboot but I can't figure out why. My configs are listed:

```
  ip inspect name Internet-out icmp router-traffic
  ip inspect name Internet-out tcp router-traffic
  ip inspect name Internet-out udp router-traffic
```

Outside interface config:

```
interface GigabitEthernet2
ip address dhcp
ip access-group Internet in
no ip unreachables
ip inspect Internet-out out
ip nat outside
ip virtual-reassembly in
duplex auto
speed auto
no cdp enable
```

Access group causing the issue:

```
ip access-list extended Internet
permit udp any any eq domain log
permit tcp any any eq domain log
permit tcp any any eq www log
permit tcp any any eq 443 log 
deny ip any any log
```

After a reboot - I have to manually do the following otherwise no inside NAT translations work -"show ip nat translations" shows nothing in the table.

```
interface GigabitEthernet2
no ip access-group Internet in
ip access-group Internet in
```

And like magic it all starts working. I've checked the running-config order and it is exactly the same after I issue the command to when it reboots. I'm stumped and can't figure this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After upgrading IOS from 15.5 to 15.5.3 I was finally able to use ZBF instead of CBAC. Because of bugs in that version you could not create policies. I was then able to remove the inspect rules and substitute them for policies and also remove the access-lists. Since making these changes, the issues on reboot and the router hanging problems (yes the outside interface would hang after 4-5 hours) have gone away completely.

It appears that there are some serious bugs in CBAC for newer IOS versions and Cisco is not going to fix them according to their own documentation. My advice is to ditch CBAC and go for Zone Based Firewall in all newer IOS versions.

Comment: You should verify which 15.5(3) version you are running. 15.5(3)M1 will reboot itself on a regular time period. This is supposed to be fixed in 15.5(3)M3.

Comment: The version is: Cisco IOS Software, C860 Software (C860VAEW-ADVSECURITYK9-M), Version 15.5(3)M, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)

Comment: 3 days without a reboot so far - it would be nice to know if my version doesn't have the bug @RonMaupin mentioned. If anyone can help it would be appreciated.

Comment: I think it was something like every 17 days, but I don't remember exactly. You can ask Cisco about it.

Comment: I bought the router through my ISP who then told after the initial issues with the policy crashes that I would need to take out and pay for a Cisco support contract! After which I forced the ISP to give me an upgrade to fix the issue as ZBF wouldn't work and under law they had to repair it or refund me. Now I'm faced with another potential issue and another argument so my first dealings with Cisco and how they support IOS have been abysmal to say the least.

Comment: You can always discuss bugs with Cisco. You would be wise to order the support since it is actually pretty inexpensive if you shop around and get the the regular business-day option.

Comment: According to the Cisco support site the following IOS version has just been released on 10th Feb - c860vaew-advsecurityk9-mz.SPA.155-3.M2.bin. According to @RonMaupin this reboot issue may still be a problem in the latest IOS version for my router. Any comments appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know, that code should be fine. You can always discuss bugs with Cisco.

Comment: 4 weeks now without a reboot. I think 15.5(3)M doesn't suffer the issue identified by @RonMaupin.